# perl pointer array reference's dereference

Tags: perl, reference, dereference

I want to get the value of a1, but I get an error message: can't use an undefined value as a scalar reference.

```
sub new{

  _name = [\\@ a1, \\@a2];

}
```

My code:

```
${self->_name}[0];   //get the pointer a1

${${self->_name}[0]}  // get the value a1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's hard to tell what your  code is here. See [how to format code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: A lot of this looks like incorrect/dangerous Perl syntax - did you put "use strict;"? Completing your example into a [mre] which gives the exact error you want to ask about would be helpful.

Comment: That code doesn't produce the error you claim it does because it doesn't even compile!

Answer (score 1):

In perl you de-reference a pointer with the "->" operator using the sigil (@$%&) followed by curly brackets only at the top level.
E.g:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
print "Outer Array:\n  " . _name() . "\n";

print "First inner Array:\n  " . _name()->[0]. "\n";
print "First Value of first inner Array:\n  " . _name()->[0]->[0]. "\n";
print "All Values of first inner Array:\n  " . join("/", @{_name()->[0]}) . "\n";
sub _name {
    my @a1 = (4 , 5 , 6);
    my @a2 = (1 , 2 , 3);
    return [\@a1, \@a2];
}
```

Might print out:

```
Outer Array:
  ARRAY(0x55f141082ec0)
First inner Array:
  ARRAY(0x55f141082e18)
First Value of first inner Array:
  4
All Values of first inner Array:
  4/5/6
```